# How to do Map of maps to List?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this code

```
Set<String> ccy = groupedPortfolio.values().stream()
            .map(accountStatusListMap -> accountStatusListMap.values().stream()
                    .map(portfolios -> portfolios.stream().map(Portfolio::getCcy)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

for translation from groupedPortfolio which is map of maps to set of currencies from Portfolios.
In my code i have error

```
Required type: Set<String>
Provided: Set<Stream<Stream<UUID>>>
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: You're getting accountId which seems to be UUID and expect String currencies?  Please provide more details about your objects and try to give [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead of `map` when transforming collections within a stream and you need to flatten them.

Comment: Show us the type of `groupedPortfolio`.

Comment: @AlexRudenko i mean getCcy there. i fix it

Comment: @Naman ty man))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this.  Convert all the streams into one large one of Portfolios.
Then retrieve the information you want via a map.

```
Set<String> ccy = groupedPortfolio.values()
     .stream()
     .flatMap(accountStatusListMap -> accountStatusListMap.values().stream())
     .flatMap(List::stream).map(Portfolio::getCcy)
     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Find another solution apart from your one:

**`Set<String> ccy = groupedPortfolio.values().stream()
                .map(accountStatusListMap -> accountStatusListMap.values().stream().map(Collection::stream)
                        .flatMap(x -> x)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                        .stream().map(Portfolio::getCcy)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                .stream()
                .map(Collection::stream)
                .flatMap(a -> a)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());`**

Check out the complete code from this **[link](https://onlinegdb.com/ryetH_9TU)**.